# Can't upload Facebook AdImage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Im trying to upload an image using the Marketing API

```
$image = new AdImage(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = 'http://www.newspringcapital.com/uploads/portfolio/homepage/Innovid%20Home.png';

$image->create();
echo 'Image Hash: '.$image->{AdImageFields::HASH}.PHP_EOL;
```

but I'm getting the following error:

"couldn't open file "http://www.newspringcapital.com/uploads/portfolio/homepage/Innovid%20Home.png"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AdImageFields::FILENAME` uses a path not a URL

Consider uploading it to your local folder than using it